# Joomla default page

Tags: php, joomla

I am using joomla 1.6
The address for example http: //mywebsite.com
Every time when I write down the link for example http: //mywebsite.com/article or every page like http: //mywebsite.com/* it is automatically jump in to the first page http: //mywebsite.com.
If I have a tab opened http: //mywebsite.com/article or every page http: //mywebsite.com/* then I can go directly to these page I want, If not, it is automatically jump to the first page.
I don't know how to change this option, so I can get in http: //mywebsite.com/article directly with out jump out to the first page.
Thank you

Comment: Why on earth are you still using Joomla 1.6?

Comment: Joomla 3.2.1 is the latest version! heres a link to download http://www.joomla.org/download.html

Comment: It's my old website for a long time, now i am unemployment and use it again, but don't have money to upgrade and im not a IT professional too, just using an old version!

Comment: You should atleast upgrade to Joomla 2.5 which shouldn't cause any problems and everything on your site should still work properly

Comment: Is there any problem when I upgrade from 1.6 to 2.5?

Comment: There shouldn't be. Joomla 1.6 and 1.7 were the short term releases before Joomla 2.5 was released. Joomla 2.5 has improved security and many more features. If you do decide to upgrade, ensure you take a backup of your 1.6 site first just incase